# Css one tag but not the other

Tags: html, css

I have html code as follows:

```
<code>concat</code>
<pre class="sourceCode haskell">
    <code class="sourceCode haskell">concat</code>
    <code> something else </code>
    some more
</pre>
```

This code is generated, so it is not an option to change it.

I want to syalize the `<code>` tags in the same way as the `pre` tags (with a border), but I don't want multiple borders when I put `<code>` within the `<pre>` tags.

Basically my question is: Is there a way to stylise `code`, only if it is not in `<pre>` tags.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style code and then style code that is a descendant of pre differently.

```
code { border: foo; }
pre code { border: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify one set of stylings for `code` and one for `pre code`.

As an example:

```css
code {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
pre {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
pre code {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<code>
  test
</code>

<pre>
  <code>
    Test code in pre
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want ...

```
pre,
code{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
pre code{
  border: 0;
}
```

... so that both are styled the same, unless the `<code>` is nested inside `<pre>`